# Parse ORM query from json

Tags: django, python-2.7, orm, tastypie, django-orm

I've seen that in tastypie, for example, one can send a query by a json request from the client, and tastypie knows to convert it (I guess) into an ORM query and execute it.

I'd like to mimic that ability so that I'd be able to convert this json:

```
{
  "foo__isnull": false,
  "name__in": "paul,george",
  "baz__fish": "blah",
  "limit": 6
}
```

into something like

```
MyModel.objects.filter(foo__isnull=False, name__in=["paul", "george"], ...)
```

without the overhead of fully using tastypie - is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `**` to pass in the query:

```
query = json.loads(your_json_string)    
MyModel.objects.filter(**query)
```

Just in case you wonder how to convert `paul,george` into a list, do:

```
query = json.loads(your_json_string)
query['name__in'] = query['name__in'].split(',')
```

Comment: Don't be so hasty. Notice how "paul,george" is not a python list. In addition, it also knows how (in addition to the example) to parse a stringed bool, for example "false" into python False

Comment: My point is to let you know about the feature for passing `**` to the `filter` function. Python json function would always convert `false` into `False`, and you could also convert `paul,george` into a list trivially, so I don't think the downvote makes much sense.

Comment: Trying to parse it by myself, iterating and handling all the options is not what I was expecting. I appreciate your help and might end up implementing it but I was hoping there's some pre-made tools for that.

Comment: Not everything is pre-made if your data doesn't obey the expected format. It's programmer's responsibility to massage the data so they could fit the data into their program. It's especially the case when you are calling 3rd party api, people from the other party doesn't have responsibility to adapt to your convention, so they often make their own. After all, if nobody is making a pre-made tool, you are the first one, right? :)

Comment: This is not "my" convention. As I mentioned this is the format tastypie is working with.